# Create a new column based on another column in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, lambda, apply

I have a df with multiple columns. One of my column is extra_type. Now i want to create a new column based on the values of extra_type column. For example

```
extra_type
NaN
legbyes
wides
byes
```

Now i want to create a new column with 1 and 0 if extra_type is not equal to wide then 1 else 0
I tried like this

```
df1['ball_faced'] = df1[df1['extra_type'].apply(lambda x: 1 if [df1['extra_type']!= 'wides'] else 0)]
```

It not working this way.Any help on how to make this work is appreciated
expected output is like below

```
extra_type  ball_faced
NaN           1
legbyes       1
wides         0
byes          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 df['ball_faced'] = df.extra_type.apply(lambda x: x != 'wides').astype(int)
```

|  | extra_type | ball_faced |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NaN | 1 |
| 1 | legbyes | 1 |
| 2 | wides | 0 |
| 3 | byes | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's no need to use `apply()` or a lambda as in the original question, since comparison of a pandas Series and a string value can be done in a vectorized manner as follows:

```py
df1['ball_faced'] = df1.extra_type.ne('wides').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
  extra_type  ball_faced
0        NaN           1
1    legbyes           1
2      wides           0
3       byes           1
```

Here are links to docs for [`ne()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html).

For some useful insights on when to use `apply` (and when not to), see [this SO question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code). TL;DR from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/18135454): **"If you're not sure whether you should be using apply, you probably shouldn't."**

Comment: I have checked both implementations with 4k rows: 0.03849387168884277 seconds  vs 0.0052607059478759766 seconds. The OP wanted to figure out .apply() method, but your solution is 10x faster.